# Change location.href with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, location-href

I need to change the location.href of some URLs on my site. These are product cards and they do not contain "a" (which would make this a lot easier).

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="product-card " onclick="location.href='https://www.google.com'">
```

I mean it is pretty simple, but I just cannot get it to work. Did not find any results from Google without this type of results, all of which contain the "a":

```
$("a[href='http://www.google.com/']").attr('href', 'http://www.live.com/')
```

Any ideas on how to get this to work with jQuery (or simple JS)?

I cannot change the code itself unfortunaltely, I can just manipulate it with jQuery and JS.

Comment: Maybe there's a reason that everything you find to do with "going to another page" uses `<a>`...

Comment: And the problem is? Adjust the selector, and the `.attr()` call. The [documentation for jQuery](https://api.jquery.com) will tell you all you need to know.

Comment: Actually catching an location.href and changing it is the issue which the documentation does not solve unfortunately. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the `onClick` for all the `class='product-card'`, you can do something like this:

```js
// All the links
const links = document.getElementsByClassName('product-card');

// Loop over them
Array.prototype.forEach.call(links, function(el) {

    // Set new onClick
    el.setAttribute("onClick", "location.href = 'http://www.live.com/'" );
});
```

```html
<div class="product-card " onclick="location.href='https://www.google.com'">Test</div>
```

Will produce the following DOM:

```html
<div class="product-card " onclick="location.href = 'http://www.live.com/'">Test</div>
```

---

Another option, is to loop over each `<div>` and check if something like `google.com` is present in the `onClick`, if so, we can safely change it without altering any other divs with the same class like so:

```js
// All the divs (or any other element)
const allDivs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

// For each
Array.from(allDivs).forEach(function(div) {

  // If the 'onClick' contains 'google.com', lets change 
  const oc = div.getAttributeNode('onclick');
  if (oc && oc.nodeValue.includes('google.com')) {
  
     // Change onClick
     div.setAttribute("onClick", "location.href = 'http://www.live.com/'" );
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="product-card" onclick="location.href='https://www.google.com'">Change me</div>
<div class="product-card">Don't touch me!</div>
```